# Why is the URL parameter value equal to "index.php"?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm using mod_rewrite with Apache and PHP to rewrite URLs for a page.
For one page on the site, I using the following, which works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(\d+)/? index.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

However, for another page on the site (the one I'm having problems with), I'm using the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(\w+)/? index.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Essentially, `\d` changes to `\w`.
For some reason, for the `\w` page, the `id` parameter is being set to `index`, not the actual value in the URL.
If I change `\w` to just `.`, then the `id` parameter equals `index.php`.

When I look at the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal, the `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` parameter is correctly set, but the `QUERY_STRING` parameter is set to either `index` or `index.php` (depending on whether I use `\w` or `.`).

What is happening here and why?
And more importantly, how can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting it to be? `\w` will match any word character so it doesn't capture the `.php` part whereas `.` matches any character and therefore captures `index.php` in its entirety.

Comment: `\w` = "word characters", basically `a-zA-Z`, with `.` NOT being one of them. doing `^(\w)` is going to capture `index` out of `index.php`, because the `.` is explicitly excluded from `\w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're rule is executing more than once as your pattern is just `^(\w+)/?` without anchor `$`.

You can fix it by including `RewriteCond` before that rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

    # If the request is not for a valid directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # If the request is not for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're right! Wow! All I had to do was add a `$` after `/?` to get it to work properly. Why does the rule execute more than once without the end anchor?

Comment: When you have `^(\w+)/?` then it matches original URI `/something` first. Which gets rewritten to `/index.php?id=something`. Now  `mod_rewrite` runs in a loop so it applies `^(\w+)/?` pattern to `/index.php` and since it matches `/index` it rewrite it to `/index.php?id=index`. It stops at this point since original and rewritten URIs are same. But also remember that if you use pattern `^(.+?)/?$` then you must use `RewriteCond` as I showed to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. It helps a lot. I ended up using `^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$`, and it works just fine without the conditionals.

Comment: Yes that will work. However keep in mind it will also write an existing directory also to `index.php`

Comment: Yes, good point. I guess the solution to that would be to have another .htaccess file within any subfolders, right? Or, of course, I could use the conditionals you suggested as well.

Comment: Yes it is not practical to have a .htaccess in each and every sub-folder. Best portable solution is to have rewrite conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that. I've never used the conditionals before, but they certainly make sense.